# Popup text box in HTML with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need to design a text box [textbox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/drie0.jpg)

As in the the above picture.

It should have two text box and if i edit one it should reflect in another(via versa).

Kindly help me on this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hi @don - please provide code you've already tried using.

Comment: show your css code please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this meet your requirements?

```js
function showPopup() {
  document.getElementById('2').style.display = "block";
}

function syncValueWith2() {
  document.getElementById('2').value = document.getElementById('1').value;
}

function syncValueWith1() {
  document.getElementById('1').value = document.getElementById('2').value;
}
```

```html
<textarea onkeyup="syncValueWith2()" id="1"></textarea>
<br>
<textarea onkeyup="syncValueWith1()" id="2" style="display: none;"></textarea>
<input type="button" value="Show Popup" onclick="showPopup()">
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```js
var textarea1 = document.getElementById("textarea1");
var textarea2 = document.getElementById("textarea2");
var button = document.getElementById("button");
function Show(button) {
if (button.innerHTML = "Show")  {
button.innerHTML = "Hide" ;
textarea2.style.display = "inline";
} else {
button.innerHTML = "Show" ;
textarea2.style.display = "none";
}
}
function change1() {
textarea2.value = textarea1.value;
}
function change2() {
textarea1.value = textarea2.value;
}
```

```html
<textarea id="textarea1" onkeyup="change1();"></textarea>
<textarea id="textarea2" onkeyup="change2();" style="display:none"></textarea> <br />
<button onclick="Show(this)">Show</button>
```

Comment: Do you mean by alert box?

Comment: no the second text box need to be hide and if i click the button it need to be display if i change the content in second box (popup box) i need to be reflect in first text...

Answer (score 0):

@Keshav solution will update everytime you finish editing the text area

If you want to update it directly when you press the key, you can use jQuery and with this code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset='utf-8' />
  <title>Test</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <textarea class="textarea-1" rows="4" cols="50">
    test
  </textarea>
  <textarea class="textarea-2" rows="4" cols="50">
    test
  </textarea>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript">
  var textarea1 = $('.textarea-1');
  var textarea2 = $('.textarea-2');

  textarea1.keyup(function() {
    textarea2.val(textarea1.val());
  });

  textarea2.keyup(function() {
    textarea1.val(textarea2.val());
  });
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: Its perfect only one change need. button need to be static, when i click it again it need to hide the 2nd text box..

Comment: I am sorry, I dont really understand what do you mean

Comment: you want the first text box will copy everything at 2nd textbox?
or you want to look the difference before and after of the 1st textbox?